# xsl-fo loop with counter

Tags: loops, xsl-fo

I am using xsl-fo and xml to generate a report. I have a query that gets values from a table to place on the pdf. Easy enough. I am querying based on a parent-child relationship. For example, the pdf displays two sections: A job title and its responsibilities. At first this was a one to one relationship. Now it has turned to a one to many relationship. So I need a way of displaying on a pdf with a Job title and then responsibilities A and then responsibilites 2, and so on. The responsibilities section has a Mod_Num (1,2,3...). So I was wondering if there is any way to loop through in the xsl-fo to grab all responsibilites for a specific Job title. I was thinking of using a where clause in the query to pull the right information

```
Where Mod_Num = 'xsl-counter'
```

SOmething like that

Hope my example wasn't too sketchy. Any help would be greatly appreciated though. Thanks

Comment: I'd say that your example is too sketchy. What exactly does the XML input look like? What exactly is the expected output?

Comment: the xml inputs are xml tags. The output is a pdf report. My main question I guess is if there is a way to loop through records using a counter in xsl fo

Comment: Still way too sketchy, I'm afraid. You say that you are using XSL-FO. How do you generate the XSL-FO markup? What are the "xml tags" that you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do that using just XSL-FO. If it's also using FTL (as in moqui or ofbiz), you can do this:

You can use an <#assign x = 0/> to set a variable.

Then use a <#list responsibilities as r>

In the <#list>, you can do an <#assign x = x+1/>.

Just inside the <#list>, you can use an <#if>.
So something like:

```
<#assign x = 0/>
<#list responsibilities as r>
    <#if x == 0>
        <fo:block>Responsibility 1: ${r.text}</fo:block>
    <#elseif x == 1>
        <fo:block>Responsibility 1: ${r.text}</fo:block>
    </#if>
    <#assign x = x+1/>
</#list>
```

I know this probably isn't exactly what you are doing, but without getting more details, it's hard to know. Hopefully it will help you out.